# Flatten Plugin: Resolve dependencyManagement of bom without inherited

Tags: maven, flatten-maven-plugin

I created an example project for this problem: https://github.com/robeatoz/flatten-resolve-dependency-management-without-inherited

Following project structure is given:

- **foo-build** as the parent for all modules
- **foo-module-a** as child module
- **foo-module-b** as child module
- **foo-module-c** as child module
- **foo-dependencies** as bom

I used the flatten-maven-plugin and the property `revision` for CI friendly builds in all modules:

```xml
<groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
<artifactId>foo-build</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>0.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>
```

The parent (foo-build) manages one external dependency:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>external.artifact</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-managed-in-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The bom (foo-dependencies) manages the foo dependencies:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-module-a</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-module-b</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-module-c</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I want that the flattened pom of the bom contains only the resolved foo dependencies without the dependencies managed by the parent (foo-build) like this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-module-a</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-module-b</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-module-c</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

How do you have to configure the flatten-maven-plugin to achieve this?

I already tried `<flattenMode>bom</flattenMode>`, but then the flattened pom does not resolve the versions:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-module-a</artifactId>
      <version>${revision}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-module-b</artifactId>
      <version>${revision}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-module-c</artifactId>
      <version>${revision}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

With the following configuration

```xml
<pomElements>
    <properties>remove</properties>
    <dependencyManagement>resolve</dependencyManagement>
</pomElements>
```

the flattened pom contains the managed dependency of the parent:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-module-a</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-module-b</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-module-c</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>external.artifact</groupId>
      <artifactId>module-managed-in-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to change your approach to more *client-centric*:

1. Make **foo-dependencies** a root project (`./pom.xml`).

   - with only `foo-*` dependencies in dependency management section
   - modules list with a single **foo-build** module (would be truncated by flatten plugin)
   - generic project properties (would be truncated by flatten plugin)
2. Make **foo-build** an intermediate project (`./foo-build/pom.xml`).

   - with third-party dependencies in dependency management section
   - with build-specific properties or profiles, required by your project (if any)
3. Retain **foo-module-*** leaf modules with **foo-build** as a parent

If you insist on plain project structure (`./foo-module-*/pom.xml`), you can use `relativePath` to point parent module, e.g.:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>stack.overflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-build</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <relativePath>../foo-build/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>foo-module-a</artifactId>
```

This way you will receive:

- clear **foo-dependencies** as you wish;
- zero copy-paste for `foo-*` dependencies;
- flexibility to build whatever and however you like in **foo-build** without side-effects on **foo-dependencies** (neither now nor in the future).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! For the given example, your solution is very good. In my real-world project, the root-project has `spring-boot-parent` as the parent with its own dependency management. For this reason, making `foo-dependencies` as the root project will unfortunately not help.

If no other person answers, I will give you the bounty anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I have like the exact same usecase and I solved it with the following configuration.

You need to apply a very specific configuration to the flatten-plugin within the pom file of the BOM module:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
        <pomElements>
            <dependencyManagement>expand</dependencyManagement>
        </pomElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`expand` means that the dependencyManagement block will be replaced with the one from the *effective pom* where all references are properly resolved. `updatePomFile` is necessary because otherwise by default, the flattened pom would not be published for poms with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

Here are the relevant parts from the flatten-plugin's documentation:

- `updatePomFile`: https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/flatten-mojo.html#updatePomFile
- Explanation for `expand`: https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/apidocs/org/codehaus/mojo/flatten/ElementHandling.html#expand

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the version with ${revision}, use ${project.version}, take a try